# Why do I get NoMethodError when using variables to access elements of a Ruby hash parsed from JSON?

Tags: ruby, json, parsing, hash, key

I'm trying to parse an example JSON file with a Ruby script that uses the JSON gem. Here's the file that I'm trying to parse:

```
{
  "page": {
    "title": "Templating Example"
  },
  "teacher": {
    "name": "Mr. Bill"
  },
  "students": [
    { "name": "Bruce Wayne", "nicknames": ["Batman"] },
    { "name": "Peter Parker", "nicknames": ["Spidey", "Spiderman", "Spider-Man"] }
  ]
}
```

I can pull data out of this JSON using the following script:

```
require 'json'
file = File.read("data.json")
        response = JSON.parse(file)
        page_title = response["page"]["title"]
```

In the above case, `page_title` returns "Templating Example"

Where I get into trouble is when I try to drop variables into my "page" and "title" places, something along the lines of:

```
var1 = "page"
var2 = "title"
page_title = response["var1"]["var2"]
```

I've tried various solutions using quotes and no quotes, escaping out the quotes, passing the variables in already formatted with the brackets and quotes but I always get an error:

```
undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

or

```
`undefined method `response' for main:Object (NoMethodError)
```

Comment: Where/by what are these errors being thrown?

Comment: What are you intending to do? Are you trying to assign a value to the page title and manipulate the original data? Are you trying to access other parts of that data?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It's not necessary, nor particularly desirable to have things like "thanks" or "any advice would be deeply appreciated". Stack Overflow questions and answers comprise an online reference book, similar to a cookbook. Salutations, valedictions and signatures are not desirable parts of the Q & A.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be

```
var1 = "page"
var2 = "title"
page_title = response[var1][var2]
```

otherwise `var1` will be evaluated as a string with the content `var1`, and not as "the content of the var1".

Answer (score 2):

### The Problem: Missing Hash Keys

> page_title = response["var1"]["var2"]

These keys aren't variables, they're strings. The string keys you're referencing don't exist in the hash you posted. With your current code, you would need:

```
{ 'var1' => {'var2' => :foo} }
```

to exist in (or be merged into) your hash for this to work. Otherwise, if the `'var1'` key doesn't exist, you can't call the `[]` method on it without raising a NoMethodError exception.

You can solve this by using variables as keys, or through other means as described below.

### Potential Solutions

You have several choices, depending on what you're really trying to do:

1. With Ruby 2.3.0 or higher, use [Hash#dig](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Hash.html#method-i-dig) to avoid exceptions when attempting to get at nested values. For example:

   ```
   response.dig 'page', 'title'
   #=> "Templating Example"

   response.dig 'var1', 'var2'
   #=> nil
   ```

   You would obviously still have to decide what to do if the return value is nil, but at least you won't get unexpected exceptions.
2. Use actual variables instead of strings to represent your hash keys. For example:

   ```
   var1 = 'page'
   var2 = 'title'

   response[var1][var2]
   #=> "Templating Example"
   ```
3. Merge in another hash to the response hash (e.g. using [Hash#merge!](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Hash.html#method-i-merge-21)) before performing your operations. For example:

   ```
   var_hash = { 'var1' => {'var2' => :foo} }
   response.merge! var_hash
   response['var1']['var2']
   #=> :foo
   ```

Any of these solutions, or a combination of them, will help you resolve your problem. What will work best for you will vary depending on your specific use case.

Comment: Very useful comments. Many thanks. Solution 2 does work for me.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are trying to use `[]` with a key (method param), that doesn't exist in your JSON. For example:

```
hash = { foo: 1, bar: 2 }
hash[:foo] #this key exists in hash
#=> 1
hash[:some_var] #this key not exists
#=> nil
hash[:some_var][:var2] #call [] method on nil class
#=>undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

If you want to add a value in your `response` hash, write it like this:

```
response[:var1] = {}
response[:var1][:var2] = your_value
```

Or:

```
response[:var1] = { var2: your_value }
```

Or maybe problem is here:

```
response["#{var1}"]["#{var2}"]
```

or

```
response[var1][var2]
```

Comment: Thanks much. I just added a clarification in my original query. The values that var1 and var2 represent are "page" and "title" (in this case) but I'm not able to substitute them this way. I'm actually writing a loop so need to be able to use variables in the hash.

Comment: Edited. try `response[var1][var2]`

Comment: Never do `"#{var1}"`. If you know `var1` is a string, just use it directly (as in your last example). If you're not sure it's a string and you need it to be a string, just do `var1.to_s`.

Comment: Absolutely agree with you. It is just an instance cases like hash["prefix_#{var}"].